# How to express logical OR in property value?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'5001207'})-[r]-> (o) WHERE (o:ProdAttrs) AND any(key in keys(o) WHERE toLower(key) contains 'Network') return o
```

In this query, if I want to express "contains Network|Phone|Smart", how to modify the query? That is the logic 'OR' in value.

Edited:

I tested this but it doesn't work:

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'5001207'})-[r]-> (o) 
  WHERE (o:Attrs OR o:ExAttrs) AND any(key in keys(o) 
   WHERE key =~ '(?!).*(network|phone).*') 
return o
```

The non-RE version works. Any errors? There is no syntax error. It just doesn't return result as expected from the .

EDIT 2:

My function to generate the query:

```
public String query_partial_match(String skuid, List<String> attrKey) {

        return "MATCH (s:Product {id:'" + skuid + "'})-[r]-> (o) " +
                "WHERE " +
                "(o:ExAttrs OR o:ProdAttrs) AND " +
                "any(key in keys(o) WHERE key =~'(?i).*(" + attrKey + ").*') " +
                "return o";
    }
```

This is my Java method to generate the query. So how to use the Java list 'attrKey' in this query?

Comment: You have a typo. Use `(?i)` instead of `(?!)`. And there is no need to lowercase 'Network' or 'Phone' using this query.

Comment: THAT"S RIGHT!!!

Comment: This question is about how to do multiple ORs in a cypher query. Your EDIT 2 should actually be a new question about how to pass parameters to a Cypher query in Java, so please create a new question (and include which Java driver or API you are using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression to test for multiple alternate string values.

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'5001207'})-->(o:ProdAttrs)
WHERE ANY(key in KEYS(o) WHERE key =~ '(?i).*(Network|Phone|Smart).*')
RETURN o;
```

`(?i)` enables case-insensitivity.

Also, if you pass in a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/syntax/parameters/) (say, `$terms`) containing the collection of target strings (e.g., `['Network', 'Phone', 'Smart']`), the query can generate the corresponding regular expression. For example:

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'5001207'})-->(o:ProdAttrs)
WHERE ANY(key in KEYS(o) WHERE
  key =~ '(?i).*(' + REDUCE(s=$terms[0], t IN $terms[1..] | s + '|' + t) + ').*')
RETURN o;
```

Comment: It looks like this RE has the same effect of 'contains'.

Comment: It is equivalent to multiple contains (ORed together), but it does it in one step, and it does not require you to convert every key to lowercase beforehand. And it also does not require you to lowercase all the target strings that you are testing for, either.

Comment: In addition, it is possible to generate the regular expression within the same query (say, if you pass in a list of target strings as a parameter).

Comment: That's exactly what I need! I have to pass a list of parameters.

Comment: My answer was updated earlier to show how to do that.

Comment: See my comment below your question.

Comment: please see my code edit again. The question is how to turn the Java List into a Neo4j List, to be used in the query generation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use OR in your WHERE clause. Might be helpful to work with the list of all lowercase props.

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'5001207'})-[r]->(o:ProdAttrs) 
WHERE any(key in [prop in keys(o) | toLower(prop)] WHERE key contains 'network' OR key contains 'phone' OR key contains 'smart') 
RETURN o
```

Comment: Because of the use of `toLower()`, the 'Network', 'Phone', and 'Smart' strings need to be in lowercase, else the query will never match anything.

Comment: Fixed, missed that.